# NHibernate Session Management in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am searching about the different ways one can manage an nhibernate session in a web api project. The simplest solution I found binds the session to HttpContext when the request begins. Other, more complex,  solutions use dependency injection.

My question is there any reason for not choosing the easiest way of binding the session to HttpContext on BeginRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is there any reason for not choosing the easiest way of
>   binding the session to HttpContext on BeginRequest?

The reason is that Web API is designed to work with OWIN. This means that it could be hosted outside ASP.NET where notions like `HttpContext` and `BeginRequest` simply won't exist. So using them you are tying your application to an ASP.NET host forever which is exactly what the designers of the Web API tried to avoid by porting it to the OWIN middleware.

So you can use the [`HttpRequestMessage.Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties(v=vs.118).aspx) dictionary instead to store your NHibernate session and achieve per-request lifetime.